# Im trying to pass controls (such as string IDs) between Page_PrerenderComplete and Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure how to pass down controls between `Page_Load` and `Page_PrerenderComplete` that are on the same c# page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Not sure how to get animallist_hf from Page_PrerenderComplete
        HiddenField animallist_hf = (HiddenField)Page.FindControl("animallist_hf");

        //Not sure how to get animallist_hf from Page_PrerenderComplete
        string animallist_str = Page.FindControl("animallist_str").ToString();

        //Not sure how to get stringSeparators from Page_PrerenderComplete
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "," };

        //Not sure how to get animallist_Array from Page_PrerenderComplete     
        string[] animallist_Array; 

        animallist_Array = sanimallist_str.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string test = (string)"ggggg".ToString();

        CheckBoxList animallist = (CheckBoxList)repeater1.Items[1].FindControl("animallist");
        foreach (string i in animallist_Array)
        {
            foreach (ListItem listItem in animallist.Items)
            {

                if (listItem.Text == i)
                {
                    listItem.Selected = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_PrerenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenField animallist_hf = (HiddenField)repeater1.Items[0].FindControl("animallist_hf");
        string animallist_str = (string)animallist_hf.Value;
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "," };
        string[] animallist_Array;

        animallist_Array = animallist_str.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string test = (string)"ggggg".ToString();

        CheckBoxList animallist = (CheckBoxList)repeater1.Items[0].FindControl("animallist");
        foreach (string i in animallist_Array)
        {
            foreach (ListItem listItem in animallist.Items)
            {

                if (listItem.Text == i)
                {
                    listItem.Selected = true;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: No one is going to debug your code for you. And no one is going to read the source comments to find out what you want. Try to reformat this to ask a specific question and show what you have done and what results you got.

Comment: What do you want the code? What is it actually doing?

Comment: Maybe you can beging telling us why you want to do it, i think there is a better aproach to do it.

Comment: Declare variables in the class instead of in the methods. Then variable is available to any methods in the class (code behind). And if you make the variable protected or public you can also use it in the aspx! (aspx is simply sub class of code behind class.. And if you are not using code behind: You should. Otherwise you will end up with gross unmaintainable code like php)

Comment: Also note that prerender happens AFTER load. So you cannot get stuff in load from pre render (without round trip to browser aka "post back")

Answer (score 0):

```
// declare class variable
int x; 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // define class variable
         x = 1;
    }

    protected void Page_PrerenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // use class variable
        if ( x == 1 ) {
            // do stuff
         }

    }
```